# Removing User Object Property

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to remove a property within a Microsoft.graph User object.
I am currently using the "Property.Remove()" method. First, I am setting the User object to a deserialized JObject.
The way I am doing this is serializing the User object into a Json string (jsonString) and deserializing jsonString (jsonStringUpdated). Afterwards, I am calling jsonStringUpdated.property("____") .Remove();
Is there a simpler way to do this? Below is an example:

```
{
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    var jsonStringUpdated = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); 
    jsonStringUpdated.Property("country").Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not say that this is simpler option, but I would say that it is better one (in terms of reusability, flexibility and possibly performance). You can create [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm#ID3RBSection):

```
    // generic type parameter can be omitted with hardcoding typeof
    // handling for multiple properties can be added
    public class IgnorePropertyResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private readonly string _propName;

        public IgnorePropertyResolver(string propName)
        {
            _propName = propName;
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);        
            if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(member.DeclaringType) && member.Name == _propName)
            {
                property.ShouldSerialize = o => false;
            }
            return property;
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass(), 
          new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
              ContractResolver =  new IgnorePropertyResolver<MyClass>(nameof(MyClass.Prop2))
          });

    Console.WriteLine(serializeObject); // prints {"Prop1":0}
```